# Use JMockit test the RESTful API,RestTemplate,error missing invocation

Tags: rest, testing, jmockit

I am learning to use the JMockit to test my Restful API.The missing invocation error is abusing me.
**The Restful API:**
@RestController
public class AgentInfoRest {

```
@Autowired
AgentInfoRepository agentInfoRepository;

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgentInfoRest.class);

@RequestMapping("/allagentInfo")
RestResponse getAllAgentInfo()
{
    RestResponse restResponse = new RestResponse();
    logger.info("getAllAgentInfo has no request parameter");
    Collection<AgentInfo> result = agentInfoRepository.getAllAgents();
    if(result.isEmpty())
    {
        restResponse.setRetCode(-1);
        restResponse.setRetMsg("Request success,no such record in db");
    }
    restResponse.setResult(result);
    return restResponse;
}
```

}
**The Test Class:**
public class AgentInfoRestTest {

```
String host = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

@Test
public void getAllAgentInfoTest(@Mocked final AgentInfoRepository agentInfoRepository) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    RestResponse restResponse = new RestResponse();
    AgentInfoRest agentInfoRest = new AgentInfoRest();
    new StrictExpectations() {
        {
            agentInfoRepository.getAllAgents(); result = null; times = 1;
        }
    };
    String url = "/allagentInfo";
    ResponseEntity<RestResponse> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(host + url, RestResponse.class);
    new FullVerifications() {
        {
        }
    };
}
```

}
**The Error:**
mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: **Missing invocation** of:
com.egoo.dao.repository.freelink.AgentInfoRepository#getAllAgents()
   on mock instance: com.egoo.dao.repository.freelink.$Impl_AgentInfoRepository@50a7bc6e

```
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Caused by: Missing invocation
    at com.egoo.dao.rest.freelink.AgentInfoRestTest$1.(AgentInfoRestTest.java:33)
    at com.egoo.dao.rest.freelink.AgentInfoRestTest.getAllAgentInfoTest(AgentInfoRestTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ... 7 more

Comment: Isn't it that the `AgentInfoRest` class is running on a different JVM instance (and process) than the one running the test? If so, it makes sense to get a "missing invocation".

Comment: I've checked,the two class are in two different processes.So is there any method to move them into one process?Or is there any method to mock a invocation in another process?

Comment: Neither. You will have to either a) write the test without making use of `RestTemplate` (ie, using `AgentInfoRest` locally), or b) let the remote process use a real `AgentInfoRepository`.